# How do I find the formula for this basic algebra problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Based on the constant in blue, for each set of known numbers in green, how do i find red? The numbers in red may actual vary a bit $\pm 1.0$, but they are consistent.

I know there has to be a formula for finding this, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

It's for solving an alignment issue with scaling an image on my website.

$$\huge\color{green}{4}\color{red}{=25}$$
$$\huge \color{green}{3}\color{red}{=37}$$
$$\huge \color{blue}{2=73}$$
$$\huge \color{green}{1.5}\color{red}{=146}$$
$$\huge \color{green}{1.1}\color{red}{=731}$$

Comment: What functions have you studied? I could make a 27th degree polynomial fit this, but I'm not sure what you are looking for

Comment: It looks like you're saying the number 4 is the same as the number 25.

Comment: I see what your saying @mathematician. Apologize for that.
Basically, given zoom level 2, the outcome will be 73. Or given zoom level 4 the outcome will be 25.

Comment: Are you asking for some function $f(x)$ such that $f(1.1) = 731, f(1.5) = 146, f(2) = 73, f(3) = 37, f(4) = 25$?

Comment: I think we should all note that $x = y$ does not mean the same thing as $x\color{red}{=}y$.

Comment: For any finite set of points $(x,~ y)$ there are an infinite number of functions which take on those values, so you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: Do you expect zoom level 1.0 to give the outcome $\infty$?

Comment: Clearly the OP desires a convex solution, with some nice smoothness properties... that is how zooming is expected to work.

Comment: From [a quick Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jlxxafxbjz), the equation $f(x) = \frac{73}{x-1}$ seems to be a good fit.

Comment: @shardulc Nice! Definitely seems close enough. Make that an answer

Comment: @shardulc. Thats it! You do not know how much you are appreciated right now, and everyone else for lending a hand. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plotting the points you provided in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jlxxafxbjz) (really, this is an amazing tool), it seems like $f(x) = \frac{73}{x-1}$ is a good fit for the points you provided. To see exactly how good the fit is you could plot the residuals in that graph too. It's simple and looks like the sort of thing a scaling function would be.